# I can't reach an endpoint in openshift via rest() component

Tags: api, rest, apache-camel, openshift, apache-camel-k

For a study project I got the task to deploy route definitions to openshift for automated route generation. I need to use openshift and camel k for this task. My problem is that no matter what I do, I am not able to reach my endpoint. Here are the things I already did:

1. Walked through this tutorial:
   https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/04/25/build-and-deploy-an-api-with-camel-k-on-red-hat-openshift/

but since camel K 1.3.1 this tutorial seems to not work anymore...

2. I found a tutorial about jetty, but in the end I got the info that for http endpoints in camel there is quarkus being used.
3. When starting to describe my endpoint in camel k I need to specify a kind of path and here is where things got complicated.

Whatching a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpVVXDnZLPo&t=385s) from Tom D I copied everything he did but the difference is he specifies a local host endpoint whereas I try to reach an endpoint in openshift.

```
    import java.time.Period;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class RestVersuch extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        ///apis/camel.apache.org/v1/namespaces/pidi-dario/integrations/rest-versuch
        rest()
                .path("/rest-versuch")

                .get()
                .route()
                .transform(simple("GET funktioniert!"))
                .endRest()

                .post()
                .route()
                .to("log:info")
                .transform(simple("POST funktioniert!"))
                .endRest();
    }
}
```

[youtube snap from example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qotK6.jpg)

[working service in openshift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCrfK.jpg)

As you can see in the pictures everything seems to work fine BUT for some reason camel shuts down shortly after starting the service from my cmd (as an admin):

[cmd info log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFQBh.jpg)

When I try to open the app from openshifts direct link that you can see in picture 4 I only get a a massage that my app is not available.

[applycation not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLN8C.jpg)

Since I am very new to this topic I really hope any of you guys can help me in this particular situation! Thanks for your time reading this post :)!

Comment: This question needs more information. How are you calling your endpoint ? It should be something like `<route_url>/<integration_path_in_your_endpoint>`

Comment: If you click on "working service in openshift" you get directed to a picture where you can see the URL of my route :)

Comment: That link should have a path appended to it afaik.

Comment: I already tried to append different things to it such as "...cloud/rest-versuch" or the self-link that you can find in the YAML file but I always get the message back that you can see in "application not available". Do you know where I can find that path you are talking about?

Comment: the application stops because you ahve knative installed (openshift serverless maybe) and so the camel-k integration is stopped when there's no traffic. If you send i.e. a post on the public endpoint, then you shoudl see that in a few seconds the pod is scaled up